# Mongoose text search not returning any results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am using Mongoose 5.7.8 for my app but the text search is not returning any results.

Here is one schema/model:

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import { IUser } from './IUser.model';
import mongooseMoment from 'mongoose-moment';

mongooseMoment(mongoose);

export interface IProfile extends Document {
  given_name: string;
  family_name: string;
  nickname: string;
  name?: string;
  picture?: string;
  locale?: string;
  updated_at?: Moment;
  email?: string;
  email_verified?: string;
  sub: string;
  user: IUser['_id'];

  bySub(sub: string): any;
}

export const ProfileSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  given_name: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: true},
  family_name: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: true},
  nickname: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: true},
  name: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: false, unique: false},
  picture: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: false, unique: false},
  locale: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: false, unique: false},
  updated_at: {type: 'Moment', required: false, unique: false},
  email: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: false, unique: false},
  email_verified: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: false, unique: false},
  sub: {type: Schema.Types.String, required: true, unique: true, index: true},
  user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

ProfileSchema.query.bySub = function (sub: string) {
  return this.where({sub});
};

ProfileSchema.index({'given_name': 'text', 'family_name': 'text', 'nickname': 'text'});

export default mongoose.model<IProfile>('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

and here is a controller that is searching the profiles:

```
const criteria = 'a';

const profiles: IProfile[] = await Profile.find(
  {
    $text:
      {
        $search: criteria,
      }
  }
);
```

Unfortunately, `profiles` is always empty, even though there are documents that match the criteria. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some consistency issues around creating the indexes. You may be firing the query *before* the indexes have been created and they possibly haven't even been created. The following works for me in local development when testing.

I recommend you rather create your indexes directly in Mongodb and remove the index creation from Moongose entirely using `autoIndex: false` in your connection string.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/tests`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, autoIndex: false});
```

But for dev and to help answer your question:

Define the indexes and then run `await Profile.ensureIndexes();` which checks the indexes for the model exist. It will run `createIndex` if needed.

See comments inline:

```
// define schema
let schema = new Schema(
    {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    {
        versionKey: false,
        timestamps: false,
        autoIndex: false // set false as this create significant load on your production database
    }
);

// define the text index
schema.index({ content: 'text', name: 'text' }, {name: 'my text index'});

// initialize the model
const Profile = mongoose.model('profiles', schema);

// insert some data
const profile = await Profile.create({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Darth "The Sith Lord" Vader',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
});

// event to notify us when indexes are created
Profile.on('index', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    console.info(`index created`);
});

// ensure we have the indexes, this will use createIndex in the background
await Profile.ensureIndexes();

// now run the query using the index
const result = await Profile.find({
        $text:
            {
                $search: 'consectetur adipiscing',
            }
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        name: 1
    }
);

console.info(result);
[ { name: 'Darth "The Sith Lord" Vader' } ]
```

Comment: It works when I add the index directly to MongoDB. Thanks!